# Natural rulers: What organisms have the most regular size?

Tags: biophysics

What organisms exhibit the most precise length scales?  E.g. are there trees with rings that are of very precise thickness, or single celled organisms which are all very nearly the same length?

In particular, it seems to me that most lengths in nature are precise only to about the 10% level.  Are there any organisms which exhibit length scales considerably more precise than this?

(Bonus points if you can tell me the most precise mass scales in nature, too.)

PS: This question is partially motivated by ongoing studies by physicists as to the origin of length scales in biology.  See [this paper](http://www.pnas.org/content/112/33/10371.full) for an example.

Comment: You mean to ask which organisms have least variability in their sizes (and converse)?

Comment: @WYSIWYG Essentially that's what I'm asking, with the caveat that I'm not necessarily concerned with overall size, but rather the size of any component of the organism.  So e.g. in the case of (say) trees, the overall height of a tree need not have small variability, so long as the growth rings have very consistent size from one tree to another.